# How to create Processer group in apache-nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to create processer-group in Nifi.from somewhere I will get the tenant name Based on tenant I want to make processer-group, is it possible through programmatically? Please reply

Comment: you can do everything through nifi api. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html

Comment: yes, I went through that but I am not able to understand where to write and through nifi-API I am not able to create process-group. Can you please assist how to use nifi-API through? HTML or java? @daggett

Comment: Done, I am able to understand thanks @daggett

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @daggett pointed out in the comments, the Apache NiFi [REST API](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html) provides documentation on the expected input and response of every API method. To discover the correct method(s) to perform a task, it is often easiest to use the NiFi UI with your browser's developer tools open. The NiFi UI is a reference implementation of an API client, as all UI activities are performed using the API. Simply execute the desired task (i.e. drag a process group onto the canvas and enter a name) and watch the resulting requests fire in the developer tools window.